Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing' from 'node_modules/jest-preset-angular/build/config/setup-jest.js'
Upgrading from angular 12 to angular 16. In the process 100% of my tests seem to be failing. All the errors seem to signify a missing node module. I am not sure what I am missing. Any help is extremely appreciated. Thanks!
error screenshot here
Here is my jest.config.js:
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@app/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/app/$1',
    '^@environments/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/environments/$1',
    '^@src/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^@assets/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/assets/$1',
    '^@styles/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/styles/$1',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.html$',
    },
  },
  globalSetup: path.resolve(__dirname, 'jest-global-setup.js'),
  resolver: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/jest.resolver.js'),
};

I have tried using jest 28.0.0. Currently using 27.5.1 in jest-environment-jsdom, jest in my package.json
